# Consolidate data from two objects into one spread sheet

Tags: powershell

I am trying to collect statistics from F5 LTM, The script is working fine when I pass one object (Throughput), Now I have modified my script and used foreach loop to collect stats from second object (activecons) but my data is getting override by the 2nd object and I only get stats from one object (activecons) on my spreadsheet. I am not sure how can consolidate data from both objects and place it on one spreadsheet. So far I have tried the following

```
$stats = "throughput", "activecons"
foreach($s in $stats){
$Query = New-Object -TypeName iControl.SystemStatisticsPerformanceStatisticQuery
$Query.object_name = $s
$query.start_time = [int][double]::Parse((Get-Date -Date ((get-date).AddDays(-7)) -UFormat %s))
$Query.end_time = [int][double]::Parse((Get-Date -Date (get-date) -UFormat %s))
$Query.interval = 0
$Query.maximum_rows = 0
}
# Make method call passing in an array of size one with the specified query
$ReportData = $SystemStats.get_performance_graph_csv_statistics( (,$Query) )

# Look at the contents of the returned data.
$ReportData




# Allocate  a new encoder and turn the byte array into a string
$ASCII = New-Object -TypeName System.Text.ASCIIEncoding
$csvdata = $ASCII.GetString($ReportData[0].statistic_data)
# Look at the resulting dataset
$csvdata


# Replace commas with tabs in the report data and save to c:\temp\tabdata.txt
$csvdata.Replace(",", "`t`t") > c:\temp\tabdata1.txt
# Allocate an Excel application object and make it visible.
$e = New-Object -comobject "Excel.Application"
$e.visible = $true
# Load the tab delimited data into a workbook and get an instance of the worksheet it was inserted into.
$wb = $e.Workbooks.Open("c:\temp\tabdata1.txt")
$ws = $wb.WorkSheets.Item(1)
# Let's remove the first row of timestamps.  Ideally you'll want this to be the 
# horizontal axis and I'll leave it up to you to figure that one out.
$ws.Range("B2").Formula = "=(A2/86400)+25569+(-5/24)"
$ws.Range("B2").AutoFill($ws.Range("B2:B388"), 0)
$ws.Columns.Item(2).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
$ws.Columns.Item(3).Entirecolumn.Select()
$ws.Columns.Item(3).Entirecolumn.NumberFormat = "0"
$ws.Columns.Item(5).Entirecolumn.Select()
$ws.Columns.Item(5).Entirecolumn.NumberFormat = "0"
#$ws.Columns.Item(4).Entirecolumn.Select()
#$ws.Columns.Item(4).Entirecolumn.Delete()
$ws.Cells.Item(1,6) = 'AVERAGE'
$ws.Cells.Item(1,7) = 'MAXIMUM'
$ws.Cells.Item(3,6) = '=AVERAGE(C2:C388)'
$ws.Cells.Item(3,7) = '=MAX(C2:C388)'



# The last row of the data is filled with NaN to indicate the end of the result set. Let's delete that row.
$ws.Rows.Item($ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Select()
$ws.Rows.Item($ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Delete()
```

I am not sure if I can consolidate this data on one spreadsheet or I need to place my data from the second object into new excel tab.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm completely misreading your code it looks like in the `foreach($s in $stats)` loop you assign an object to `$Query` and then do nothing with it. The loop then runs again and assigns a different object to `$Query` which leads to you only getting (activecons) in your output.

You could try changing `$Query` to an array and then appending, might give you the result you're expecting.

```
$stats = "throughput", "activecons"
$Query = @()

foreach($s in $stats){
    $Q = New-Object -TypeName iControl.SystemStatisticsPerformanceStatisticQuery
    $Q.object_name = $s
    $Q.start_time = [int][double]::Parse((Get-Date -Date ((get-date).AddDays(-7)) -UFormat %s))
    $Q.end_time = [int][double]::Parse((Get-Date -Date (get-date) -UFormat %s))
    $Q.interval = 0
    $Q.maximum_rows = 0
    $Query += $Q
}
```

Now that `$Query` is an array, you'll need to change the way you refer to it later. I don't have the F5 module so I can't test, but try this:

```
$ReportData0 = $SystemStats.get_performance_graph_csv_statistics($Query[0])
$ReportData1 = $SystemStats.get_performance_graph_csv_statistics($Query[1])
```

Then look at the contents of `$ReportData0` and `$ReportData1`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I tried with the array before but it did not work data was overwriting each time. Again i tried your method and I am getting an error with overwritten data. The error was gone when i removed + sign from $Query += $Q .  The error is as follows  Cannot convert argument "objects", with value: "System.Object[]", for "get_performance_graph_csv_statistics" to type "iControl.SystemStatisticsPerformanceStatisticQuery[]": "Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" 
value of type "System.Object[]" to type "iControl.SystemStatisticsPerformanceStatisticQuery"."

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to change the way you use `$Query` later in the script, I'll update the answer with a suggestion.

Comment: In $ReportData0 and $ReportData1 I am getting active connections and Throughput respectively.  I am not sure how can I now consolidate data on one spreadsheet. I am able to open two spreadsheets having contents of activecons and throughput, but I need them on one spreadsheet.

Comment: any solution for this ?

Comment: Try `$csvdata = $ASCII.GetString($ReportData0.statistic_data)` then `$csvdata += $ASCII.GetString($ReportData1.statistic_data)`?

Comment: After trying this, First, I got the results of throughput and after it ends I get the result of connections on one spreadsheet. They are on top of each other. I need them in separate columns. Right now with only throughput, I have columns like this Column A (Time stamps), Column B(Date), Column C (In Throughput) Column D (empty) Column E (Out Throughput). That's it for throughput. I need to see the result of connection which is only one column in Column F.

Comment: any recommendation?

Comment: Are the number of rows in each dataset the same? How will you know which row from the first set to add the entry from second set?

Comment: The number of rows for both datasets is same i.e. 339 when I fetch dataset via above script but when I try to fetch same data from GUI instead of the script with a same one-week parameter I get the same number of rows for both dataset but this time the number of rows is 388. I do not know why this difference coming though in the script I set the interval to 0.

Comment: You could construct a loop to iterate through the first dataset and append the column from the matching row in the second set. Have a look at [add-member](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member)